# How can I clear a cached add-in start page in Outlook on Windows 10 1903?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've updated the html, js, and css files used by the add-in, but it appears that the start page (URL in the SourceLocation tag for the pane) is cached.
In our case it's clear that the start page is cached from a previous version because we have changed paths in our latest version, so every file requested from the start page returns a 404 and a blank page is displayed to the user.

The windows version is 1903, with the latest Outlook(desktop) from Office 365.

I have tried deleting the cache from the Edge Dev Tools, and it had no effect.
I've also turned on "Always refresh from server" in the dev tools and then ran `location.reload()` from the Console, to no effect.

The add-in is installed from a file, and I have tried removing the add-in and re-adding it, also to no effect.

I don't see the same behaviour in either Mac OS Outlook or Outlook on older versions of Windows (pre 1903).

I'm ideally looking for a solution that will work for end users, but any solution would be helpful.

Comment: Just to verify, have you updated the SourceLocation url in the manifest to point to your new html, js, and css files and re-installed the updated manifest? Are you using a Taskpane add-in? Another way to force the add-in to reload is to click the taskpane add-in to set focus to the add-in and press Ctrl+F5.

Comment: The url to the start page has not changed (which I think is part of the problem), we'd prefer not to have to update the manifest after releases.
Yes, this is a taskpane add-in.
I'm reasonably sure Ctrl+F5 didn't work in this case, but I'll go back and check.

Comment: If there are no manifest changes, then clearing the cache via Edge Dev Tools should force the add-in to grab the new files. I am not able to repro this issue. You can also add the no-cache header to prevent caching your add-in's files.